# What cometd configurations to use to reduce 402 error occurrences?

Tags: java, networking, jboss, cometd

We have implemented a Java servlet running on JBoss container that uses CometD long-polling. This has been implemented in a few organizations without any issue, but in a recent implementation there are functional issues which appear to be related to the network setup of this organization.

Specifically, around 5% of the time, the connect requests are getting back 402 errors:

```
{"id":"39","error":"402::Unknown client","successful":false,"advice":{"interval":0,"reconnect":"handshake"},"channel":"/meta/connect"}
```

Getting this organization to address network performance is a significant challenge, so we are looking at a way to tune the implementation to reduce these issues.

Which cometd configuration parameters can be updated to improve this?
maxinterval, timeout, multiSessionInverval, etc?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "402 unknown client" error is due to the fact that the server does not see `/meta/connect` heartbeat messages from the client and expires the correspondent session on the server. This is typically due to network issues.

Once the client network is restored, the client sends a `/meta/connect` heartbeat message but the server doesn't have the correspondent session, hence the 402.

The parameter that controls the server side expiration of sessions is `maxInterval`, documented here: https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_java_server.

By default is 10 seconds. If you increase it, it means you are retaining in the server memory sessions for a longer time, so you need to take that into account.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I had already tried increasing that parameter with no impact, however looking back I see I had the parameter name as "maxinterval", not "maxInterval" so possible that my change wasn't picked up because of the incorrect case. I will test again. Thx.